# Проблема с установкой Voyager в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

- Laravel Version: 5.4
- Voyager Version: "^0.11.3"
- PHP Version:  7.1
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 5.7

#### Description:

Никак не могу установить нормально админку. Все делаю по инструкции в документации, а на выводе не вижу таблицу стилей и не правильный путь для картинок. 
Посмотрите порядок установки мой, может где-то что-то не так. 
Приложил видео.

[Видео- Установка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQmM0XW1s5A&feature=youtu.be)

[Ссылка на Voyager и такс там.](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/850)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, что нужно было - посмотреть [Issues](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20assets%20is%3Aclosed) на эту тему :)
По поводу стилей описано [тут](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/811):

> Run `php artisan vendor:publish` and ensure that you have the port in the `APP_URL` environment.

Данного шага не было замечено у вас на видео.

По поводу [ресурсов](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/834) `/storage`:

> You have already ran `php artisan storage:link`.

Исправьте `APP_URL`, удалите скопированные ассеты из вендоров и попробуйте выполнить эти команды.

Comment: Спасибо, но вот че-то я тут потерялся. Никак не пойму что писать в APP_URL - например папка у меня css мне нужно http://css вставить? И что делает php artisan vendor:publish?

Comment: Хотяяя :) Вроде все сделал. Ток теперь в public ке висят папки vendor и link storage. Меня напрягает vendor я туда закинул только tcg?

Comment: Не понимаю вопроса :) Что конкретно напрягает? Что внутри public/vendor находится?

Comment: Да. Именно это напрягает :) Нахождение в publicке папки vendor/tcg/..